# Card image won't show when placed in row

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

When I put a card inside of a row the image disappears and when its outside the row the image appears. Have no idea why. When its outside the row it shows.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container" id="mainContainer">
  <div class="row mt-5 custom-row2 p-5 align-items-center">
    <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
      <div class="row g-0">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="https://cdn.business2community.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png" class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which row -- you've got two in that example? The one with class "g-0" or the one with class "mt-5" ?

Comment: You shouldn't have rows nested adjacent, and you shouldn't put inline styles on them, especially ones that mess with the natural layout flow. There are better ways to limit width.

Comment: Are you including the bootstrap stylesheets?

Comment: _Tag_ your Bootstrap version, as you did for HTML. Don't tack it onto your title.

Comment: Sorry its my first time using stack overflow. my real problem is that im genarating this code with javascript and when i do the image wont show (getting the image from local storage) i was going to edit the javascript in, i was not expecting so many answers so fast. However the problem is the same. (i will edit in the javascript)

Comment: Usually the col element falls immediately inside the row element. You've done things differently and haven't explained what your goals are. Please provide a description or mockup of your desired outcome.

Comment: No worries. Keep at it. We're just trying to get you to a solution. I suggest you leave the JS out. It's a distraction. Once you have the layout sorted you can work on scripting it.

Comment: Thanks i really messed up the question. Do you think it would be okay to delete this post and create another question structured properly?